# How to create a general linear program without any visualisation with Optaplanner?

Tags: project, linear-programming, optaplanner, timefold

Suppose I already have my model, constraints etc. How do I input these to Optaplanner so I can obtain a solution, without having to worry about visualisation or any other secondary goals? Among the many examples and quickstart options, none correspond to mine and all are cluttered with visualisation so I cannot decipher where the linear program model and constraints are located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Take a look at [the hello world quickstart](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/tree/stable/hello-world)** of Timefold ([fork of OptaPlanner](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork/)).

It has no visualization cluttering. It's just [the domain classes](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/tree/stable/hello-world/src/main/java/org/acme/schooltimetabling/domain), [the constraints](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/blob/stable/hello-world/src/main/java/org/acme/schooltimetabling/solver/TimeTableConstraintProvider.java) and [the app to run them](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/blob/stable/hello-world/src/main/java/org/acme/schooltimetabling/TimeTableApp.java).

All of which are explained in [this getting started guide](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/quickstart/hello-world/hello-world-quickstart.html).

For example the constraints:

```
@Override
public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return new Constraint[] {
            // Hard constraints
            roomConflict(constraintFactory),
            teacherConflict(constraintFactory),
            studentGroupConflict(constraintFactory),
            // Soft constraints
            teacherRoomStability(constraintFactory),
            teacherTimeEfficiency(constraintFactory),
            studentGroupSubjectVariety(constraintFactory)
    };
}

Constraint roomConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    // A room can accommodate at most one lesson at the same time.
    return constraintFactory
            // Select each pair of 2 different lessons ...
            .forEachUniquePair(Lesson.class,
                    // ... in the same timeslot ...
                    Joiners.equal(Lesson::getTimeslot),
                    // ... in the same room ...
                    Joiners.equal(Lesson::getRoom))
            // ... and penalize each pair with a hard weight.
            .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
            .asConstraint("Room conflict");
}
```

Comment: [Link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251006/flagging-link-only-answers) are not supported on StackOverflow.